# Fourier transform of images and phase filters

Tags: image-processing

What are the known possibilities to date for filtering the phases of an image and what are they used for?
Phases are used in some edge detection algorithms.
They are also used for cross correlation of 2 images.
Is there something more? (I'm thinking about the same principle used with the amplitudes, bandpass filtering)

Comment: Are you asking for general uses of the phase component, or specifically the application of "filtering the phases"? The latter is something which is totally destructive and never done to my knowledge.